# How to get the text form the font tag in php

Tags: php, regex, rss

Currently i am working on a project in which i am showing goolge news using google news feed dynamically. I have shown image, News Title but i am not able to extract the description of the news. Here is the code which i am using:

```
<?php
$url = "https://news.google.com/news?cf=all&hl=en&pz=1&ned=in&q=india+news&output=rss"; // url to parse
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url); // XML parser
$title = $rss->channel->item[0]->title; // getting first news title echo $title;
preg_match_all('/<img\s+.*?src=[\"\']?([^\"\' >]*)[\"\']?[^>]*>/i',$rss->channel->item[0]->description,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER);echo "<pre>";print_r($matches[0][0]); // i am getting the first news title image//now i want to get the description of the news, and for that i am using below code for getting the text between the <font> tag but there is more than one <font> tage. So how can i get the description of the first news.
$pattern = "/<font ?.*>(.*)<\/font>/";preg_match($pattern, $rss->channel->item[0]->description, $matches);echo "<pre>"; print_r($matches[0][0]);
?>
```

if you print the `$rss->channel->item[0]` then you will get the title, image and description of the first image.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you use a mixture of regex and dom parsing? In this case, parsing alone would be more than sufficient.

Comment: @Jan how can i get the Description of first news using  dom parsing, do you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

```
// url to parse
$url = "https://news.google.com/news?cf=all&hl=en&pz=1&ned=in&q=india+news&output=rss"; 
// XML parser
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url); 
// getting first news desc 
$desc = $rss->channel->item[0]->description; 
$desc = (array)$desc;
$desc = $desc[0];

echo $desc;
```

And you can continue with:

```
$pattern = "/<font ?.*>(.*)<\/font>/";
preg_match($pattern, $desc , $matches);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches[0]);
```

The output is:

---

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="7" style="vertical-align:top;"><tr><td width="80" align="center" valign="top"><font style="font-size:85%;font-family:arial,sans-serif"></font></td><td valign="top" class="j"><font style="font-size:85%;font-family:arial,sans-serif"><br><div style="padding-top:0.8em;"><img alt="" height="1" width="1"></div><div class="lh"><a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;ct2=in&amp;usg=AFQjCNGGty5KP4Coz6rRkvg4GOnvdGX1Jw&amp;clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&amp;cid=52779050953564&amp;ei=ZtLKVvCAOYf_yAPt8JH4Cg&amp;url=http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/industry/energy/power/india-set-to-seal-major-power-deal-in-bangladesh-beating-china/articleshow/51084850.cms"><b><b>India</b> set to seal major power deal in Bangladesh, beating China</b></a><br><font size="-1"><b><font color="#6f6f6f">Economic Times</font></b></font><br><font size="-1">After China&#39;s recent success in pushing development projects in Sri Lanka, a breakthrough in Bangladesh would be welcome news for <b>Indian</b> officials who have long fretted over Beijing&#39;s encroachment on to territory it considers its own back yard.</font><br><font size="-1" class="p"></font><br><font class="p" size="-1"><a class="p" href="http://news.google.com/news/more?ncl=dlwfqfFszEiI06M&amp;authuser=0&amp;ned=in"><nobr><b>and more&nbsp;&raquo;</b></nobr></a></font></div></font></td></tr></table><pre><font style="font-size:85%;font-family:arial,sans-serif"></font></td><td valign="top" class="j"><font style="font-size:85%;font-family:arial,sans-serif"><br><div style="padding-top:0.8em;"><img alt="" height="1" width="1"></div><div class="lh"><a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;ct2=in&amp;usg=AFQjCNGGty5KP4Coz6rRkvg4GOnvdGX1Jw&amp;clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&amp;cid=52779050953564&amp;ei=ZtLKVvCAOYf_yAPt8JH4Cg&amp;url=http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/industry/energy/power/india-set-to-seal-major-power-deal-in-bangladesh-beating-china/articleshow/51084850.cms"><b><b>India</b> set to seal major power deal in Bangladesh, beating China</b></a><br><font size="-1"><b><font color="#6f6f6f">Economic Times</font></b></font><br><font size="-1">After China&#39;s recent success in pushing development projects in Sri Lanka, a breakthrough in Bangladesh would be welcome news for <b>Indian</b> officials who have long fretted over Beijing&#39;s encroachment on to territory it considers its own back yard.</font><br><font size="-1" class="p"></font><br><font class="p" size="-1"><a class="p" href="http://news.google.com/news/more?ncl=dlwfqfFszEiI06M&amp;authuser=0&amp;ned=in"><nobr><b>and more&nbsp;&raquo;</b></nobr></a></font></div></font>
```

If you want it broken into more pieces,

```
$pattern = "/<font ?.*>(.*)<\/font>/U";
preg_match_all($pattern, $desc , $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: hey Alex, i want only News Description not title and image, the above code gives does't give only Description of news which i want.

Comment: Added an update. Although the script *did* get (only) the description, you may want to test out the last preg_match_all, as it generates a bit more elements, but some may be what you need.

Comment: If it's still not what you're after, can you update the question with the expected output?

Comment: Hello Alex, yes it solved my problem, i have broken it more pieces but it still not giving the description then i have got the description by jQuery selector .lh > font:nth-child(5) and that did for me. Thank you for you valuable time for helping me on this problem.